# SupervisorD spawning process continuously when running laravel queue

Tags: laravel, lumen, supervisord

I am running Lumen queue in daemon mode using SupervisorD. Lumen jobs runs successfully but SupervisorD crashes.

```
laravel-worker_11: ERROR (abnormal termination)
laravel-worker_10: ERROR (abnormal termination)
laravel-worker_00: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

If I add the **startsecs=0** in supervisor conf it starts spawning the workers constantly instead of reusing the same worker for all jobs.

```
2019-03-06 10:02:28,637 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_01' with pid 31529
2019-03-06 10:02:28,638 INFO success: laravel-worker_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2019-03-06 10:02:28,777 INFO exited: laravel-worker_02 (exit status 1; expected)
```

This is causing load on server. Ideally Supervisor should just spawn one process and continue to server all jobs from it because of demon mode .

**Supervisor config**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/web/artisan queue:work --queue=server_level,app_level --tries=1 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/web/storage/logs/worker.log
startsecs=0
exitcodes=0,1,2
```

Comment: What is your Supervisor config?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson config added in original question

Comment: If you want it to spawn one process, then you should change `numprocs` to `1` instead of `3`